# discord.py command to connect to a bot

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing, discord.py, python-multithreading

I'm trying to do a command like `.addtoken <token>` that's connecting to a bot for 15 minutes and disconnect.
The problem is that when I try to connect to the bot, it fails and print:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop`

I tried different ways like threading.Thread, multiprocessing.Process and

```
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop) <----
asyncio.ensure_future(bot.run(token))
loop.run_forever()
```

but it doesn't work.
if someone can help me, thanks :smile: